# Ios 10 iPhone 7 Keyboard disappears when receiving notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios10, uiwindow

I have a UITexField in a chat view controller.
When I'm editing my answer in the textfield, everything works fine execpt when I receive a push notification from my application.

This push notification is handled by my controller and a UIWindow is displayed on the top of the view controller. But the keyboard disappears .. only on my iPhone 7 and ios 10.

It works great on iPhone 6 and ios 9.3 for instance.

I guess it's related to ios 10 and UIWindow / UITextField, but I don't know what to do to fix that issue.

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for when the application becomes active, either by implementing

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_: UIApplication)
```

in your appDelegate, or through notification center with

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appBecameActive), name: Notification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive, object: nil)
```

When the user closes the notification window, you will receive this event, and then you can make the textfield active again with

```
textfield.becomeFirstResponder()
```

to bring back the keyboard.